# App that screenshots Find My Friends a a preset time every day

Tags: iphone, module, jailbreak

I want to write an app that screenshots find my friends at a designated time each day. Would something like this even be possible? I am very new to the development world having only watched the Stanford tutorial videos.

Comment: This question doesn't follow stack overflow rules. You are asking too vague question. I would recommend to read stack overflow faq, try to break down your questions to more specific questions and ask them.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve this with the iPhone SDK.

Comment: He did apply the `jailbreak` tag, so it's reasonable to assume that he/she's not limited to only what's in the public SDK.